# php object operator -> without instance?

Tags: php, object, operator-keyword

I have the following code in script I implement and it does work correctly, just want to understand:

```
   $variable1 = function1();  // function1 is a class method, it’s file included per require_once 
   $ variable1 -> function2(); // function2 is a class method, it’s file included per require_once
```

Isn’t -> here an object operator?
But there is no initialized instance save in $variable1.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 6):

That just means that `function1()` returns an object.

Hence you can use that object and it's functions.

Example:

```
class Test {
    function function2(){
        echo "Hi";
    }
}

function function1(){ return new Test; }


//SO:

$variable1 = function1();  
$variable1->function2();
```

Comment: function1()->function2()   // PHP 5.4